# how covert post into other language in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

In wordpress how to convert a post data into other language,i am given the xml response to mobile device.so each post is create in english but i have to response in chines and other language support,there are plugin like global translator but it use ajax,but i want the local function for translation.i am running wordpress 2.8

Please reply as soon as posssible
have dream day
Thanks in advance

Comment: please take the time to check your post for typos and spelling errors before submitting.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [Google Ajax Translation](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-ajax-translation/) plugin?

Comment: yes,but this not for site,i want to send the response to mobile device,so is there any plug-in that convert the data?
I check for qtranslator i think it is OK,but u have provide data in both languages 
Thanks for your response
have dream day

Comment: i solve the it by adding the qtranslator,that add all data into database with "<!--en-->string<---->", where "en " is the language name ,if have any query about this then i can help u.
Thank You
Have Dream Day